# How do I format a field in views?

Tags: views, 8

I have an FAQ page, where in the title it has some html tags, I would like to show the title in the views. When the view is displayed, it is showing html tags as well. How can I get the html processed value.

Is it possible?

Comment: In which version of Drupal 7||8?

Comment: @Smalution Drupal 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked title field's settings section in views.
There is a option for "Style settings" you can check the option for restrict or add new html tags.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're putting `<h1>` tags in your node title, do not do that. Simply when you add the title field, go to style settings and add the H1 here. There are other options like `strong` and `p` in this drop down box.

[image]

**OR**

Alternatively, you could simply re-write the results and write your HTML around the `{{ title }}`

[image]